# What gui(RDBMS) to use for MariaDB on Linux?

Tags: linux, database, sql

I recently installed [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) on my [ArchLinux](https://www.archlinux.org/) and would like to have some GUI program for me to interact with the databases more easily. I tried MyS[QL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) but it doesn't seem to connect properly to the MariaDB and after research it looks like it has been broken for quite some time.

You can view a [Bug Thread here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78947), or a [Unix related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252275/mysql-workbench-warning-when-connecting-to-mariadb) here.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hello Mr. Nicky - I am not going to pretend to know much about your question, but I edited your answer to reference a Unix post, can you please [Edit] your question if the question I linked is an identical issue?  The question I found seemed more related to a warning, not a failed connection - "Yes this is expected, because MySQL Workbench is an Oracle product and it does not officially support MariaDB which is actually a MySQL competitor. Workbench is warning you about potential incompatibilities, not necessarily detected ones. In most cases, it can be safely ignored."

Comment: what about [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) or [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) as an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

I use MariaDB on Arch Linux as well and I can recommend DBeaver.

Free Universal Database Tool https://dbeaver.io/

> Free multi-platform database tool for developers, SQL programmers,
>   database administrators and analysts. Supports all popular databases:
>   MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQLite, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase,
>   MS Access, Teradata, Firebird, Derby, etc.

Arch Linux - dbeaver 5.2.4-1 (x86_64) https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/dbeaver/

You can install on Arch with:

```
pacman -S dbeaver
```

See the DBeaver Wikipedia entry here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBeaver

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) by Jetbrains.  It is platform independent and can be used for a multitude of database types by downloading the relevant driver - this is managed via the interface when setting up a connection.

This will allow you to perform the functions you require, but doesn't offer the database design ability which MySQL Workbench had, but will allow you to create, modify, drop tables, as well as perform queries, see the tables easily and perform other functions.

If you choose to migrate away from MariaDB to another database store, or have another project which uses a different database, you can use the same tool.